# CriteriaQuery в Hibernate поиск по нескольким параметрам

Tags: java, hibernate, criteriabuilder

Как используя `Criteria` реализовать выборку данных из таблицы следующим образом. Во-первых есть класс `Patient` описывающий таблицу БД.

В классе есть поля id, fam, im, ot. Мне нужно чтобы поиск осуществлялся только по тем полям, которые заполнил пользователь. Например если ввели фамилию и отчество, то искать людей у которых фамилия и отчество начинаются с тех данных которые ввел пользователь. Если например ввели id, фамилию и отчество искать тех у кого они совпадают. Написал метод, который делает примерно такое, но не знаю как реализовать поиск по нескольким полям, а также для fam, im, ot поиск через like типа такого `where fam like 'Фамилия%' and im like 'Имя%' and ot like 'Отчество%'`

```
private void test2search() {
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try (Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Patient> query = builder.createQuery(Patient.class);
        Root<Patient> root = query.from(Patient.class);

        query.select(root).where(
                builder.equal(root.get("fam"), txtFieldFam.getText().trim())
        );

        org.hibernate.query.Query<Patient> q = session.createQuery(query);

        List<Patient> list = q.getResultList();

        for (Patient p: list) {
            System.out.println(p.getFam() + " * " + p.getIm() + " * " + p.getOt());
        }

        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (transaction != null) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для реализации `like` используйте метод билдера `like` и добавьте необходимое выражение к искомой строке:

```
builder.like(root.get("fam"), txtFieldFam.getText().trim()+"%")
```

Для объединения запросов используйте методы `and` и `or`:

```
builder.and(builder.like(root.get("fam"), txtFieldFam.getText().trim()+"%"), builder.like(root.get("im"), txtFieldIm.getText().trim()+"%");
```

Comment: Спасибо. буду пробовать. А чем отличается использование Hibernate Search от Criteria и в каких случаях использовать то или иное решение?